# Как считать данные из текстового файла с разделителями?

Tags: java

Нужно считать данные из текстового файла в двумерный массив. Данные хранятся в файле формата .txt вот в таком виде: 
1 2 4 
2 3.4 5 
22 0 0

Как это сделать?

```
        Scanner scanner = null;
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(new File("matrix.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] string = line.split(" ");
```

Все, наладил это дело. Просто поздновато и мозг не работает уже)

Вопрос только один - как считывать до тех пор, пока есть что считывать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> while (scanner.hasNext()) {

Comment: да, спасибо, только что вот справился с этим...

Answer (score 0):

Я другой сделал:
private void OpenTextFile()
{

```
    Scanner scanner = null;
try {
    scanner = new Scanner(new File("c:\\2x3x4_48.txt"));
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

    String line = new String();

    String[] str=new String[5]; //= line.split("  ");

System.out.println(str.length);

for (int i=0; i<5; i++)    
{   
    line = scanner.nextLine();        
    //System.out.println(qator);        
    str[i]=line;
    System.out.println(str[i]);
}    
}
```